# Is this urn puzzle solvable?

Tags: probability, puzzle, balls-in-bins

Sent to me by a friend, I'm stumped.

We have an urn. It is first filled with balls of $C$ different colors, ${N_1,N_2,...N_c}$ of each of the colors. Lastly, a ball with a distinct marking is added.

We are not given $C$ or any of the $N$ values.

A machine removes the balls without replacement until the single ball with the distinct marking is picked.

We are given a vector of probabilities ${p_1, p_2,..., p_m}$ that one or more of the complete sets of the colored balls has been picked and the ball with the distinct mark *has not been picked* for picks $1, 2, ...,m$ where the $m_{th}$ pick has probability 0 (all balls including the marked ball have been picked).

The task is to find the probability that a success occurs (some complete set of one of the colors is drawn before the marked ball is drawn) *at some (any) point* during the picking process, given *only* the probability vector of the individual pick steps.

We obviously know from the vector the smallest of the $N$ and the total number of colored balls (the first and last non-zero elements in the vector), but that seems of little utility.

I don't think there's enough information in just the probability vector to answer the question.

Am I wrong?

Edit: A simple example.

Say the urn has 1 red, 2 blue, 3 green balls, plus the ball with the marking.

The probability that we've seen the red, or seen the 2 blues, or seen the 3 greens, or any combination of these sets, without having seen the marked ball is a hypergeometic distribution, with probabilities $\left\{\frac{1}{7},\frac{2}{7},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{7},\frac{2}{7},\frac{1}{7},0\right\}$ for the 1st, 2nd,..., 7th draw.

Using inclusion-exclusion it can be seen that the probability over a sequence of 7 draws without replacement that we've seen at least one of the sets of 1/2/3 balls *before the marked ball was drawn* is $\frac{64}{105}$.

So, given *only* the probability vector here of $\left\{\frac{1}{7},\frac{2}{7},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{7},\frac{2}{7},\frac{1}{7},0\right\}$, with *no other information* about how many colors nor how many of each, etc., can the latter probability of $\frac{64}{105}$ for *some* success over the course of emptying the urn be derived?

Comment: What's the aim of the task is not clear: what exactly is the difference between the probabilities to be found and those given? a small example might be helpful

Comment: @GCab - sincere apologies for delay in reply - family emergency. Please see example I've edited into the question.

Comment: Wish you overcome the emergency at best.  Now, with the example given the question is more clear. I will work on that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's indicate with
  - $s$ = success = the clearing  of whichever first full set of balls;
  - $f$ = failure = the pick of the marked ball;
  - $x$ = ininfluent = the pick of a ball, excluding the marked one, which does not lead to clear a set for the first time.
  - $m$ = total number of balls, including the marked one

The components of the vector $p$ shall actually be defined as
*the probability $p_k$ of having a success at, or before, pick $k$* **and** *a failure at any of the following picks*.

So
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & p_{\,k}  = P\left( {\left[ {{\rm s} \le k} \right]\; \wedge \;\left[ {k + 1 \le {\rm f}} \right]} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = P\left( {\left[ {{\rm s} \le k} \right]\;|\;\left[ {k + 1 \le {\rm f}} \right]} \right)\;P\left( {\left[ {k + 1 \le {\rm f}} \right]} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = c_{\,k} {{m - k} \over m} \cr} 
 } \tag{1}$$
where the *a priori* probability of extracting the marked ball at any pick is constant and equal to $1/m$, and
with the vector $c$ giving the conditional probability.
We have that $p_m=0$, $c_{m-1}=1$, so that we can put $c_m=1$, and we can add a $p_0=c_0=0$.

Let's consider now the following scheme made by partitioning the possible results of the $k$-th pick.
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
p_{\;k - 1} \;\matrix{
    \to  & {q_{\,1,\,k - 1}  = P\left( {} \right.} & {\left[ {{\rm s} \le k - 1} \right]} & { \wedge \;\left[ {k = {\rm x}} \right]} & { \wedge \;\left[ {k + 1 \le {\rm f}} \right]} & {\left. {} \right) \to }  \cr 
    \to  & {q_{\,2,\,k - 1}  = P\left( {} \right.} & {\left[ {{\rm s} \le k - 1} \right]} & { \wedge \;\left[ {k = {\rm f}} \right]} & { \wedge \;\left[ {k + 1 \le {\rm x}} \right]} & {\left. {} \right)}  \cr 
   {} & {q_{\,3,\,k - 1}  = P\left( {} \right.} & {\left[ {\neg \,{\rm s} \le k - 1} \right]} & { \wedge \;\left[ {k = {\rm s}} \right]} & { \wedge \;\left[ {k + 1 \le {\rm f}} \right]} & {\left. {} \right) \to }  \cr 
 } \;p_{\,k} 
 } \tag{2}$$
rows 1 and 2 sums to $p_{k-1}$, while rows 1 and 3 give $p_k$.

Consider then that we have

$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & \left[ {k + 1 = {\rm x}} \right]\; \wedge \;\left[ {k + 2 \le {\rm f}} \right] =   \cr 
  & \left( {\left[ {k + 1 = {\rm x}} \right]\; \wedge \;\left[ {k + 2 = {\rm f}} \right]\; \wedge \;\left[ {k + 3 \le {\rm x}} \right]} \right) \vee   \cr 
  &  \vee \left( {\left[ {k + 1 \le {\rm x} \le k + 2} \right]\; \wedge \;\left[ {k + 3 = {\rm f}} \right]\; \wedge \;\left[ {k + 4 \le {\rm x}} \right]} \right) \vee   \cr 
  & \quad \quad  \vdots   \cr 
  &  \vee \left( {\left[ {k + 1 \le {\rm x} \le m - 1} \right]\; \wedge \;\left[ {m = {\rm f}} \right]\;} \right) \cr} 
 } \tag{3}$$
where each set on the RHS is equi-probable, since they are a permutation of each other.

Therefore
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & q_{\,1,\,k}  = P\left( {\left[ {{\rm s} \le k} \right]\; \wedge \;\left[ {k + 1 = {\rm x}} \right]\; \wedge \;\left[ {k + 2 \le {\rm f}} \right]} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {m - k - 1} \right)P\left( {\left[ {{\rm s} \le k} \right]\; \wedge \;\left[ {k + 1 = {\rm f}} \right]\; \wedge \;\left[ {k + 2 \le {\rm x}} \right]} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {m - k - 1} \right)q_{\,2,\,k}  \cr} 
 } \tag{4.a}$$
or
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
p_{\,k}  = q_{\,1,\,k}  + q_{\,2,\,k}  = \left( {m - k} \right)q_{\,2,\,k} 
 } \tag{4.b}$$

Putting (2) and (4) together
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left\{ \matrix{
  q_{\,1,\,k}  + q_{\,2,\,k}  = p_{\;k}  \hfill \cr 
  q_{\,1,\,k}  + q_{\,3,\,k}  = p_{\;k + 1}  \hfill \cr 
  \left( {m - k} \right)q_{\,2,\,k}  = p_{\;k}  \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  q_{\,1,\,k}  = {{m - k - 1} \over {m - k}}p_{\;k}  \hfill \cr 
  q_{\,2,\,k}  = {1 \over {m - k}}p_{\;k}  \hfill \cr 
  q_{\,3,\,k}  = p_{\;k + 1}  - {{m - k - 1} \over {m - k}}p_{\;k}  \hfill \cr}  \right.
 } \tag{5}$$

Eq. (1) and (5) provide all the basic vectors you may want to derive from $p$.
In particular $q_{3,\, k-1}$ is the *Probability Mass Function* that the success be attained at (exactly) the $k$-th pick.

**example**

For the example that you gave, we get the following table of results

[image: N1+Nc_1]

which returns in fact the $64/105$ probability of getting a success all over the $7$ picks.
Also note that in the example, either the $p$ (that you already gave) and the $c$ and the $q$'s have been checked against a computer computation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $q_i$ be the probability of success and that the marked ball is picked at step $i+1$. Is it not true that $q_i=p_i/(M-i)$ where $M$ is the total number of balls? I might be misunderstanding the problem but it seems to me then that the desired probability is the sum $\sum_i q_i$.

I just want to point out that it seems I did understand the problem correctly and the formula I provided works. I will use your example:

64/105=(1/7)/6+(2/7)/5+(2/5)/4+(3/7)/3+(2/7)/2+(1/7)/1

So the problem is very much solvable.