# Probability of drawing some set of colors before any of another color is drawn?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

While pondering my [somewhat related urn question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401046/is-this-urn-puzzle-solvable), I've gotten hung up on the following:

Suppose I have an urn with balls marked $\{a,b,b,c,c,c,d,d,d\}$.

I remove the balls one at a time without replacement.

I'd like to calculate the probability that by the time the urn is emptied, I've seen the single $a$ ball, or the two $b$ balls, or the three $c$ balls, or any combination of these, *before* I see some $N$, $1<=N<=3$ of the $d$ balls.

I started with what I thought would be the simple case of $N=1$, where the probabilities for each case for balls $a, b, c$ is $\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{1+3}{1}}$,$\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{2+3}{2}}$ and $\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{3+3}{3}}$ respectively, or $\left\{\dfrac{1}{4},\dfrac{1}{10},\dfrac{1}{20}\right\}$.

I then applied inclusion-exclusion resulting in a probability of $\dfrac{287}{800}$, but enumerating the possible outcomes shows me that's wrong, it should be $\dfrac{53}{168}$.

How would I go about getting the probability here correctly?

Comment: Any response to my answer, Apple?

Answer (score 1):

Inclusion-Exclusion works:

$1/4+1/10+1/20-1/20-1/35-1/56+1/84=(210+84+42-42-24-15+10)/840=(304-39)/840=265/840=53/168$